# Group pages from one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, group-by

I have these information in a `page table` in my db,

```
page_id     page_title

1           xy {a}
2           kp {a}
3           xyz {b}
4           mno {b}
5           abc {c}
6           mno {c}
7           qwe {c}
```

I use **curly brackets** to group pages, such as page `xy` and `kp` belong to the group of  `a`.

So I want to return the result in this information,

```
group_title     page_title
a               xy
a               kp
b               xyz
b               mno
c               abc
c               mno
```

But **maximum of two pages** in each group.

Can I use SQL query to achieve this or PHP?

This is what I am working on by using REGEXP...

```
SELECT 
p.page_title REGEXP '{[a-z]}' AS groupTitle

FROM pages AS p

ORDER BY p.page_created DESC
```

I get this result,

```
groupTitle
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here is my query,

SELECT *

```
FROM(
    SELECT 

        p.page_id AS page_id,
        p.page_url AS page_url,
        SUBSTRING(p.page_title,LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}',p.page_title)) AS group_title,
        p.page_created AS page_created,
        @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number

    FROM root_pages AS p

    WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
    AND p.page_id != '8'
    AND p.page_hide != '1'
    AND p.category_id = '1'

    ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC


) a
```

where  row_number <= 2

result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    row_number
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   NULL
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   NULL
42      qwe         {b}         2011-10-21...   NULL
41      rty         {b}         2011-10-21...   NULL
40      tyu         {c}         2011-10-21...   NULL
39      ghj         {c}         2011-10-21...   NULL
59      sss         {c}         2011-10-21...   NULL
```

But I still have the problem to limit the number of row from each group, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column called group_id (or the like) to your page table.

Select from the db with `WHERE group_id =` if wanting to select one group or `ORDER BY group_id` to, well, order by group.

**EDIT**

If you must stick to this concept, you could split the page_title into relevant components. I'm not going present you a working query and sorting routine, but to get you started:

```
$page_title_separated = preg_split("/[\{\}]+/", $page_title);
```

where `$page_title` is a page title from your db.

Following your example (1st row entry), this would result in

```
$page_title_separated[0] => xy
$page_title_separated[1] => a
```

well, and for the sake of completeness, let it be mentioned that there'd be a `$page_title_separated[2]`, which would be empty. Also, the real title, i.e. `$page_title_separated[0]` would end in a whitespace.

I assume you know how to sort arrays in php and what to do with this data later on.

There's a multitude of slicker ways of doing this, but - I can't stress this enough - the slickest remains a third column.

Comment: Thanks. I have thought of that but the problem is I don't want to add another column to the table...

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Then why do you have 2 columns? Combine the `page_id` and `page_title` ino one: `page_id_title{group}` with (sample data): `1-xy{a}`

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Sorry if the previous comment seems ironic. What Johannes suggests is the best way, normalize the table and store different attributes in different columns.

Comment: And you don't need regex to separate the two values you have in the column. Only some combination of string functions, like `LOCATE()`, `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, `SUBSTRING`. Then, look in the `[greatest-n-per-group]` tag for your maximum-2-per-group requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will look into them! :-)

Comment: I think I kind of getting the answer but still got a small problem, please see my edit above... thanks.