# Group pages and get x number of row from each group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Following up from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870221/group-pages-from-one-column) I made earlier, I made the query below but it cannot limit certain number of row from each group,

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT p.page_id AS page_id,
               p.page_url AS page_url,
           SUBSTRING(p.page_title,LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}',p.page_title)) AS group_title,
               p.page_created AS page_created,
               @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number
          FROM root_pages AS p
         WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
           AND p.page_id != '8'
           AND p.page_hide != '1'
           AND p.category_id = '1'
      ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC) a
 WHERE row_number <= 2
```

result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    row_number
----------------------------------------------------------
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   NULL
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   NULL
42      qwe         {b}         2011-10-21...   NULL
41      rty         {b}         2011-10-21...   NULL
40      tyu         {c}         2011-10-21...   NULL
39      ghj         {c}         2011-10-21...   NULL
59      sss         {c}         2011-10-21...   NULL
```

But I want to get this as the result,

result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    row_number
----------------------------------------------------------
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   1
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   2
42      qwe         {b}         2011-10-21...   1
41      rty         {b}         2011-10-21...   2
40      tyu         {c}         2011-10-21...   1
39      ghj         {c}         2011-10-21...   2
```

Any idea where I have missed?

**EDIT 1:**

Query,

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT p.page_id,
               p.page_url,
               SUBSTRING(p.page_title, LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}', p.page_title)) AS group_title,
               p.page_created,
               @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number
          FROM root_pages AS p
          JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @url) r -- Initialize the variable
         WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
           AND p.page_id != '8'
           AND p.page_hide != '1'
           AND p.category_id = '1'
      ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC) a
```

result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    row_number
----------------------------------------------------------
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   1
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   2
42      qwe         {b}         2011-10-21...   3
41      rty         {b}         2011-10-21...   4
40      tyu         {c}         2011-10-21...   5
39      ghj         {c}         2011-10-21...   6
59      sss         {c}         2011-10-21...   7
```

Query,

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT p.page_id,
               p.page_url,
               SUBSTRING(p.page_title, LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}', p.page_title)) AS group_title,
               p.page_created,
               @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number
          FROM root_pages AS p
          JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @url) r -- Initialize the variable
         WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
           AND p.page_id != '8'
           AND p.page_hide != '1'
           AND p.category_id = '1'
      ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC) a
WHERE a.row_number <= 2
```

result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    row_number
----------------------------------------------------------
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   1
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   2
```

Query,

```
SELECT *

FROM(
    SELECT 

        p.page_id AS page_id,
        p.page_url AS page_url,
        SUBSTRING(p.page_title,LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}',p.page_title)) AS group_title,
        p.page_created AS page_created,
         @url = p.page_url,
               @row_number := CASE 
                                WHEN p.page_url = @url THEN @row_number + 1 
                                ELSE 1
                              END AS row_number

    FROM root_pages AS p
    JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @url) r -- Initialize the variable

    WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
    AND p.page_id != '8'
    AND p.page_hide != '1'
    AND p.category_id = '1'

    ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC


) a 
where  row_number <= 2
```

result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    row_number
----------------------------------------------------------
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   1
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   1
42      qwe         {b}         2011-10-21...   1
41      rty         {b}         2011-10-21...   1
40      tyu         {c}         2011-10-21...   1
39      ghj         {c}         2011-10-21...   1
59      sss         {c}         2011-10-21...   1
```

**EDIT 2:**

Query,

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    @r := CASE WHEN @g = a.group_title THEN @r+1 ELSE 1 END AS r,
    @g := a.group_title AS dummy

FROM(
    SELECT 

        p.page_id AS page_id,
        p.page_url AS page_url,
        SUBSTRING(p.page_title,LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}',p.page_title)) AS group_title,
        p.page_created AS page_created

    FROM root_pages AS p

    WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
    AND p.page_id != '8'
    AND p.page_hide != '1'
    AND p.category_id = '1'

    ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC

) a

JOIN (SELECT @r := 0, @g) r -- Initialize the variable
```

Result,

```
page_id page_url    group_title page_created    dummy       row_number
44      abc         {a}         2011-10-21...   {a}                 1
43      def         {a}         2011-10-21...   {a}                 1
42      qwe         {b}         2011-10-21...   {b}                 1
41      rty         {b}         2011-10-21...   {b}                 1
40      tyu         {c}         2011-10-21...   {c}                 1
39      ghj         {c}         2011-10-21...   {c}                 1
59      sss         {c}         2011-10-21...   {c}                 1
```

**ANSWER:**

```
SELECT *

FROM
(
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        @r := CASE WHEN @g = a.group_title THEN @r+1 ELSE 1 END AS r,
        @g := a.group_title AS dummy

    FROM(
        SELECT 

            p.page_id AS page_id,
            p.page_url AS page_url,
            SUBSTRING(p.page_title,LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}',p.page_title)) AS group_title,
            p.page_created AS page_created

        FROM root_pages AS p

        WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
        AND p.page_id != '8'
        AND p.page_hide != '1'
        AND p.category_id = '1'

        ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC

    ) a

    JOIN (SELECT @g:=null, @r:= 0) n -- Initialize the variable
) b
WHERE r <= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query didn't initialize the `@row_number` variable:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT p.page_id,
               p.page_url,
               SUBSTRING(p.page_title, LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}', p.page_title)) AS group_title,
               p.page_created,
               @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number
          FROM root_pages AS p
          JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @url) r -- Initialize the variable
         WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
           AND p.page_id != '8'
           AND p.page_hide != '1'
           AND p.category_id = '1'
      ORDER BY p.page_backdate DESC) a
WHERE a.row_number <= 2
```

Otherwise, you need to use a `SET` declaration before the query you posted.

Secondly, what you posted does not include the CASE statement necessary to reset the variable so you get 1+ for each `page_url`

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT p.page_id,
               p.page_url,
               SUBSTRING(p.page_title, LOCATE('{',p.page_title),LOCATE('}', p.page_title)) AS group_title,
               p.page_created,
               @url = p.page_url,
               @row_number := CASE 
                                WHEN p.page_url = @url THEN @row_number + 1 
                                ELSE 1
                              END AS row_number
          FROM root_pages AS p
          JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @url) r -- Initialize the variable
         WHERE p.parent_id = '8'
           AND p.page_id != '8'
           AND p.page_hide != '1'
           AND p.category_id = '1'
      ORDER BY p.page_url, p.page_backdate DESC) a
WHERE a.row_number <= 2
```

IME, the variable works on InnoDB tables but wasn't consistent against MyISAM.

Comment: thanks. the first query shows the row number but the second does not. However, the first query still does not return the query I am after as the row number are - `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` please see my edit above.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Ah, you want the ranking on the `group_title`.  Have to run to work, but you should have enough to work with until I get home from work.

Comment: I tried that but I get `1,1,1,1,1,1,1` in the number row  Please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: got it worked now after changing this line `JOIN (SELECT @g:=null, @r:= 0) n -- Initialize the variable` thanks.